# Forward and Back navigation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want to have simple forward/back navigation that is controlled through jQuery. Currently I have the following code:

```
$("#main-navigation a").bind("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $(target).offset().left,
        scrollRight: $(target).offset().right
    }, 1200,'easeInOutBack');
});
```

and HTML

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  

<div id="home" class="panel">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/landing.png" width="1024" height="768" title="landing page" />

    </div>
</div>

<div id="explore" class="panel">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/pageTwo.png" width="1024" height="768" title="page" />

    </div>
</div>
```

Ultimately the DOM with have quite a few div's with, so I would like a relatively simple method of having jQuery move between each div (forward and back), hopefully without resorting to a plugin.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance